# Is there a way to change git branch after a build step in TFS CI build?

Tags: git, tfs, tfsbuild

Background: 
Environment is TFS 2015 CI + git. I have this case I need to update DB from development branch to have up to date DB version. After this I need to run tests from last released code for backward compatibility to check my DA.

Question: 
How to achieve flexibility and change the initial branch and source code in TFS build after a build step ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to have a step that similar to Get Sources. Get Sources is a default step and it gets sources that defined in Repository tab:

[image]

To have a custom Get Sources step, you could run a PowerShell or a Cmd script step to get sources that you want.